# Сравнение значений свойств объектов JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты, сравнение

Добрый день,недавно начал изучать JS. Вопрос мой следующий:
Существует два обекта:

```
function myRandom (from, to)  {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
}

var ship = {
    x: myRandom (0, 10),
    y: myRandom (0, 10)
};
```

и

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
var shot = {
    x: function(){
        var data = prompt('Введите X координату?');
        if (data >= 0 && data <= 10 && isNumeric(data)){
            return data;
        }else{
            return shot.x();
        }
    },
    y: function(){
        var data = prompt('Введите Y координату?');
        if (data >= 0 && data <= 10 && isNumeric(data)){
            return data;
        }else{
            return shot.y();
        }
    },

};
```

Как правильно сравнить на равенство значения записываемые в их свойства?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Вы не можете сравнивать яблоки (числа в первом объекте) и апельсины (функции во втором объекте). Они по определению не могут быть равны и это лишено всякого смысла (оставим за скобками возможность использования `valueOf`).

С другой стороны, вы, можете сравнивать **значения** свойств первого объекта с **результатами работы** методов второго объекта. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
if (ship.x == shot.x() && ship.y == shot.y()) {
    console.log('Ба-бах!');
}
```

Comment: если делать так,то методы вызываются непосредственно в проверке и при первом же false проверка заканчивается..... Если методы вызвать до проверки, то при проверке они все равно вызываются....... Как выйти из положения? использовать доп. переменные,записать дуда результаты работы методов,а потом сравнить? или же вообще отказаться от такого подхода и реализовать функции отдельно и записать их результат уже непосредственно в свойства shot? Как будет правильней?

Comment: Вы вполне можете использовать дополнительные переменные для хранения результата вызова `shot.x()`/`shot.y()`. Как правильнее -- зависит от контекста. В данном конкретном случае я, скорее всего, выделил бы создание объекта `shot` со **свойствами** (не методами) `x` и `y`, а затем уже проводил бы сравнение.

Comment: Спасибо,в принципе на этом и я остановился.